# How to make a torch tensor version of ImageOps.Solarize?

Tags: opencv, pytorch, python-imaging-library

So [ImageOps](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageOps.html) has a PIL augmentation called Solarize, is there a PyTorch Tensor version of this? As in given a torch tensor can it solarize that tensor then return it? The issue with ImageOps's version is that it only does 1 image at a time so I can't do batch solarize augmenting of multiple tensors that have been converted from PIL images.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pil-imageops-solarize-method/

Comment: [Kornia](https://github.com/kornia/kornia) has a couple versions of solarize added since version 0.4.0
https://kornia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=solarize&check_keywords=yes&area=default